# Implementing rev command in C using POSIX system functions

Tags: c, linux, file, operating-system, reverse

I am trying to implement the rev linux call in C using only system calls. I was able to implement it but my code also reverses the lines of the files as well so line 1 is the last line in the file now. The last line also does not jump into a new line on stdout. I'm not sure why it is doing this.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define LINE_BUFFER 1024

int charCount(const char *name1);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if(argc ==2){
        charCount(argv[1]);
    }else{
            printf("Provide a file\n");
}
return 0;
}


int charCount(const char *name1)
{
    char buffer[LINE_BUFFER];
    int fd;
    int nread;
    int i = 0;
    if ((fd = open(name1, O_RDONLY)) == -1)
    {
      perror("Error in opening file");
      return (-1);
    }

    int size = lseek(fd,-1,SEEK_END);
    while(size>=0)
    {
        nread=read(fd,buffer,1);
        write(1,buffer,1);
        lseek(fd, -2,SEEK_CUR);
        size--;
    }
    close(fd);
    return(0);
  }
```

input

```
Contents of file 1:
Hello World
Hi World
```

Output

```
dlroW iH
dlroW olleH
```

Desired output:

```
dlroW olleH
dlroW iH
```

Comment: Your code isn’t using any syscalls.

Comment: @Dai read, write, lseek are all linux system calls.

Comment: They’re POSIX system functions. I thought you meant you’d be using the `syscall` function.

Comment: @Dai Oh okay, I will reword to avoid confusion

Answer (score -1):

Your code clearly reads the file backwards, one character at a time, printing each character as it reads it. Why would you think it would reverse line by line? It makes no attempt to even notice where each line ends.

If you read a file backwards, the last character you'll read (and therefore the last character you'll print) is the first character in the file, which is not normally a newline character.

Comment: It does notice when each line ends when it reads. I don't have to code that, i'm talking about file structure if all the text is not a single line. If theres a new line in the file it will print it in stdout on the next line.

Comment: My issue is that rev produces the desired output while my program produces the normal output I pasted. I want to replicate rev and was wondering if I can do that?

Comment: @HotWheels Have you tried debugging your code and seeing why it prints lines backwards instead of forwards? Have you e.g. tried stepping through it for the input lines `Hi` and `ho` and seeing why it outputs `\n` and `o` first, instead of `i` the way you expect?

Comment: @hotwheels: the first character you read is the last character in the file, not the last character in the first line of the file. If you want to reverse each individual line in the file, keeping the files in order, you must read the lines in order and reverse each line individually.